# Calling Firebase Analytic's getInstance() every time vs. storing instance as a static variable in Application class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying decide which of the following is the proper way to do this:

1. Calling `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Context)` from every activity, fragment, and service that I'm logging an event from.

or

2. Calling `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Context)` once from `Application` class and keeping it around as a public static variable. Then, from everywhere I need this I can call `MyAppClass.mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent()'.

Will any of the above methods have a undesired impact on the events that are automatically collected and/or do either of those have an efficiency gain over the other?

Many thanks!

Comment: Select a correct answer.

Comment: @fahmy Did you get any chance to find out the difference of  using 1 and 2? I am using Firebase V 10.2.0. And looking upon the usage of context inside the Firebase decompiled classes, I am seeing the context is used to get application context only. For activity and stuff, there is method `firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen`where we can name the activity and stuff. So, my guess right now is that using application context is enough, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @laaptu Nope, apart from the answer below, haven't got any new info on this.

Comment: You need to be a little bit careful because it's possible to access `MyAppClass.mFirebaseAnalytics` when it is still null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics) states:

> public static FirebaseAnalytics getInstance (Context context)
>
> Returns the singleton FirebaseAnalytics interface.

So I don't see any particular reason why you can't just have a singleton instance in your code.
There won't be any noticeable efficiency gains with either approach. If you're looking into the second option, it might be worth considering doing this with dependency injection and a simple wrapper around the analytics instance to increase the testability of your code.

Comment: I am worried that Firebase might use the context to derive something about life-time or flow of application. All guidelines I've read only states it should be put in Activity.

Comment: Response to jayeffkay's comment: if it's a singleton and you're not passing in a lifecycle owner, why would it matter where you initialize it? Looking at the docs I see there are already some automatically collected events https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485